# How to implement a matched filter

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a template. I compute the impulse response of the matched filter by taking the inverse Fourier Transform of the conjugate of the Fourier transform of my template. And I would like to perform the matched filtering operation on one of my available EEG channels using the 'filter' command in Matlab. Using the filter command the coefficient 'b' is my impulse response? Moreover, I would like to implement Matlab code to threshold the output of the matched filter to detect peaks.How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please add a little more detail to your question. What have you tried? What problems are you having with the with the `filter` function?  You are speaking in jargon, which suggests you understand the problem, but your question indicates that you don't understand what you are doing. Help us figure out what part you *actually* need help with.

Comment: @nispio I have a template. I compute the impulse response of the matched filter by taking the inverse Fourier Transform of the conjugate of the Fourier transform of my template. And I would like to perform the matched filtering operation on one of my available EEG channels using the 'filter' command in Matlab. Using the filter command the coefficient 'b' is my impulse response? Moreover, I would like to implement Matlab code to threshold the output of the matched filter to detect peaks.How can I achieve it?

Comment: Great! Now we are getting closer to an answerable question. (Maybe you should consider editing your question instead of adding details in the comments.) Now, what have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: I am not sure if I should replace 'b' coefficient with the impulse response or the conjugate of FT. About the threshold I have no idea how to do it and I am waiting a suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a start for you,

```
% A template is given
temp = randn(100,1);

% Create a matched filter based on the template
b = flipud(temp(:));

% For testing the matched filter, create a random signal which
% contains a match for the template at some time index
x = [randn(200,1); temp(:); randn(300,1)];
n = 1:length(x);

% Process the signal with the matched filter
y = filter(b,1,x);

% Set a detection threshold (exmaple used is 90% of template)
thresh = 0.9

% Compute normalizing factor
u = temp.'*temp;

% Find matches
matches = n(y>thresh*u);

% Plot the results
plot(n,y,'b', n(matches), y(matches), 'ro');

% Print the results to the console
display(matches);
```

As Andreas mentions in his answer, there is no need for the fourier transform.  If you have a time-domain template, then its matched filter is simply a time-reversed version of itself (which I achieve with `flipud`).  As you go along, you will find that there are *many* nuances to be worked out.  This code works great because I am in control from start to finish, but once you start working with real data, things get much more complicated.  Choosing an appropriate threshold value for example will require some knowledge about the data that you will be working with.

In truth, peak detection can be a very non-trivial task depending on the nature of your signals, etc.  In my case, peak detection was easy because my signal was completely uncorrelated with the template, except at the point in the middle, and I also knew exactly what amplitude I was expecting to see.  All of these assumptions are over-simplifications of the problem which I used to demonstrate the concepts.

Comment: In case anyone tries to implement this example in Python -- the only nontrivial change is that `filter(b, 1, x)` becomes `scipy.signal.lfilter(b, np.ones(1), x)`.

Answer (score 4):

Practically, you do this

```
 y = filter( h, 1, x )
```

with h the impuse response and x and y input and output signals.
The matched filter is nothing else than a correlator that correlates with a given signal pattern.

It has a impulse response which is just the time reverse of the signal pattern you try to look for.

So by the way: If you have a measured signal pattern, reverse it and set this as impulse response of a FIR filter. There is no need to do this in the frequency domain if you have measurement in the time domain (both approaches are equivalent but one is more error prone then the other)